# how to get the correct value from json (php)?

Tags: php, jquery, json

update_modal(bootstrap)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit：</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="body">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="product_title" id="title">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.php">Update</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

trigger the update_modal(bootstrap)

```
    <td>
       <a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#updateModal'>
       <button class='btn btn-success' id='edit' data-id='$product_no'>Edit</button>
       </a>
    </td>
```

js

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $(document).on('click','#edit',function () {
              let id=$(this).attr('data-id');
              // console.log(id);
              $.ajax({
                  url:'get_record.php',
                  method:'post',
                  data:{
                      p_no:id
                  },
                  dataType:'JSON',
                  success:function (data) {
                        // $('#body').html(data);
                      console.log(data[0]);
                      console.log(data[1]);
                      console.log(data[2]);
                  }

              });
          });
      })

  </script>
```

get_record.php

```
<?php
include ("db.php");
 global $conn;
if (isset($_POST['p_no'])){
    $p_no=$_POST['p_no'];
    $query="select * from products where p_no='$p_no'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $user_data=' ';
        $user_data [0]=$row['product_title'];
        $user_data [1]=$row['date'];
        $user_data [2]=$row['product_price'];
//        echo $pro_title;
    }
    echo json_encode($user_data);
}
```

> My problem is when I click the edit button, the update_modal displays successfully, but it doesn't get correct values from my database. I click F12 on my chrome and it tested like this photo

[image]

[image]

Comment: data =  jQuery.parseJSON(data) and then use it

Comment: You're vulnerable to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: yeah,I'm a freshman, I need to study harder. Thanks, suggestions.@AhmedSunny @Andreas

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing `$user_data` in `get_record.php` as a string: `$user_data = ' ';`

Try initializing that variable as an array instead: `$user_data = [];`

Because you initialize `$user_data` as a string, setting `$user_data[0]` only sets the first character of the string to the first character of the value `$row['product_title']`.

---

EDIT: As noted in the comments, you are also opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks by inserting posted data directly into your SQL here:

```
$p_no=$_POST['p_no'];
$query="select * from products where p_no='$p_no'"
```

You should escape all user inputs before using them in a query. One way to do that for MySQL in PHP:

```
$p_no=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['p_no']);
$query="select * from products where p_no='$p_no'"
```

Using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) would be ideal.

Comment: @donghero The only real answer to prevent sql injections are prepared statements!